# Newly Created Objects from Class Return Undefined

Tags: javascript

I've created a Player class with some methods in it. I can create a player successfully, but when I go to call another method on the newly created player, I get `undefined`.

While the Player class will ultimately be used in another class `class Scoreboard extends Player`, I can't see why I can't invoke functions on a Player object.

Here's my Player class:

```
class Player {

  constructor(player_id, score) {
   this.player_id = player_id;
   this.scores = [score];
   this.total = score;
    }

  addScore(score) {
    this.total += score;
    this.scores.push(score);
  }

  averageScore() {
    return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
  }

  resetScore() {
    this.scores = [];
    this.score = 0;
    }

  };
```

I create a new Player with the following: `const john = new Player(2, 50);` and call `john`, which in my console returns:

```
Player {player_id: 2, scores: Array(1), total: 50}
player_id: 2
scores: (2) [50, 70]
total: 120
__proto__: Object
```

Immediately after that, I call `john.addScore(70)` and get `undefined`. I would have thought that using `this` would prevent any undefined errors. What's wrong with my class?

Comment: If the function doesn't return anything, it'll print `undefined` in console. Try logging the instance of the `Player` object instead.

Comment: Returning `this`  from a function will do what you want

Comment: It's ok for a function to return undefined.  In your case the function modifies its object and doesn't need to return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addScore() returns undefined, that's what you see on the console. It's not an error.

Comment: How does it even return?

Comment: Functions without return statement implicitly return undefined.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Guess I needed to wake up some more before working on this